# Rotating Axis/Vector2 around origin

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I would like to rotate a vector2/values i get from the x and y of my controller joystick by an angle.

for example a basic example would be if i was to press forward with the stick giving me a a value of x: 0 & y: 1, then rotated that by 90 degrees it would give me a value of x:1 & y:0.

This image demonstrates what i want to do also. I appologies that it is poorly drawn its just quick.
[image]

I need help where i am going wrong.
I'm not great with vectors but i tried this equation which makes sense to me.
[image]

I translated that into c# like this, but it doesn't work properly as the axis aren't producing values as they should do and the values they give are often exceeding 1 which is the max value i put into it.

```
Vector2 rotatedAxis = new Vector2 (
    inputValues.right * Mathf.Cos(rotationAngle) - inputValues.forward * Mathf.Sin(rotationAngle),
    inputValues.forward * Mathf.Cos(rotationAngle) + inputValues.right * Mathf.Sin(rotationAngle)
);
```

The angle isn't an issue that gives me the the rotation from the forward line, which on the graph would be (0.1). Bit of added info if wanted about this angle, just gets the angle player is rotated from normal forward. I want to just transfer that rotation angle onto the axis as well so i get values that have been offset by that angle.

Can anyone help. What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Your `rotatedAxis` seems right. Make sure you're passing `rotationAngle` in radians. Could you give an example of a coordinate and angle where the behaviour is unexpected?

Comment: I hadn't been passing it in radians, it was a float worked out by the normal PI way. It gave me the right angle, but just changed it to radians and it seems closer but still not right.

before i continue, does this now seem right?
float rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(body.transform.forward.x, body.transform.forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

Comment: Since you're passing `rotationAngle` to `Cos`, it should be in radians so there's no need to multiply by `Rad2Deg`.

Comment: Testing it now that seems to have fixed it thank you so much. massive help

Comment: @cdo256 consider converting your comment to an answer so other StackOverflow users can discover your solution to the presented problem

Comment: @Matster2 Make sure you accept that answer so it's clearly marked as a solution

Comment: How do i make it an answer. I can only post my own. I cant find promoting my question or the commented answers.